# oracle sql check constraint for number to_char

Tags: oracle, constraints, ddl, ora-00907

This is a homework problem that I'm inputting on oracle live sql website:

```
Create table student (regno number (6), mark number (3) constraint b check (mark >=0 and
mark <=100));
Alter table student add constraint b2 check (length(regno<=4));
```

It keeps throwing a "missing right parenthesis" error on the second line to `Alter`.  I read elsewhere this is a generic error for syntax but for the life of me, even if I copy and paste the code from the source material into the SQL worksheet or retype it about 20 times now, I keep getting the error.

I also tried casting to char as regno is a number.

```
Alter table student add constraint b2 check (length(to_char(regno)<=4));
```

But I get the same error.

Comment: Well, it's only homework. Otherwise a character restriction on a numeric value would make little sense. As is, `length(to_char(regno)) <= 4` means `regno >= -999 and regno <= 9999`, if I'm not mistaken, which is a rather odd restriction :-)

Comment: This lab sheet has specs listing Windows NT and Windows 7 so I just complained to the instructor about that and the errata in the given code in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You comparison operator(`<=`) should be outside the `length` function:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
  2      REGNO   NUMBER(6),
  3      MARK    NUMBER(3)
  4          CONSTRAINT B CHECK ( MARK >= 0
  5                               AND MARK <= 100 )
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> -- Solution of the question
SQL> ALTER TABLE STUDENT
  2      ADD CONSTRAINT B2 CHECK ( LENGTH(REGNO) <= 4 );

Table altered.

SQL>
```

One suggestion, If you want to restrict the `REGNO` to only 4 digits then convert the data type of `REGNO` as `NUMBER(4)`

Cheers!!